# How to set the variable not to be displayed? The php language I use Thank you?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

How to set the variable not to be displayed? The php language I use Thank you?

[image]

"cmd + shift + o"  Search for symbols in files.
not autocomplete.

Comment: Please see the picture.

Comment: If you're asking about autocomplete in VS Code, disable `Suggest: Show Variables` option.

Answer (score 0):

php variables are not visible in frontend until you print it.
to hide html input fields or something, you can use style="display:none"

or if condition